# JetBrains @Contract using field

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've got the following class*:

```
public class MyClass {

  @Nullable
  private String mString;

  /* ... */

  public boolean contains(@NotNull final String text) {
    if(!isNullOrEmpty()) {
      return mString.contains(text);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public boolean isNullOrEmpty() {
      return mString == null || mString.isEmpty();
  }
}
```

Now at `mString.contains(text)`, IntelliJ warns me that `mString` might be `null`, even though it is guaranteed that it isn't. I've noticed JetBrains has the [`@Contract`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/-contract-annotations.html) annotation. Is there a way I can annotate `isNullOrEmpty()` in such a way that I don't get this warning when the method returns `true`?

I am hoping the `@Contract` annotation will come close to the [Java Modeling Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Modeling_Language) functionality, like so:

```
//@ ensure \result == true ==> mString != null;
public boolean isNullOrEmpty() {
  return mString == null || mString.isEmpty();
}
```

Furthermore, I'd like `isNullOrEmpty()` to remain parameterless, since it is part of the public API.

<sub>*Just a fictional class for demonstration purposes :) The actual code uses a more complex class.</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `mString` is mutable so between the check '`isNullOrEmpty`' and the access '`mString.contains`' mString value can be changed. So it is the reason why `@Contract` annotation works only for method parameters. You can use `@Contract` if your method `isNullOrEmpty` looks like:

```
public boolean isNullOrEmpty(String pString) {}
```

Comment: This indeed works, thanks. I'll let the question sit around a bit though to see if my original method can work as well.

Comment: Are you missing the return type from that signature? i.e. should it not be "public boolean isNullOrEmpty( String s){ /* test/return 's is null/empty' */ }

Answer (score 2):

Well, because you've annotated `mString` with `@Nullable`, `mString` could very well be `null`.  This is static analysis at work; you've already declared that this field may or may not be `null`, so IntelliJ is going to inform you about that.

Consider why the field is annotated with `@Nullable`.  Maybe it should be `@NotNull`?

Keep in mind, I'm only getting the warning in the `contains` method, since IntelliJ is doing the smart thing; it knows that if `mString == null`, the other condition *won't be evaluated*.

As a reminder:  `@Contract` [only applies to the arguments](http://javadox.com/org.jetbrains/annotations/13.0/org/jetbrains/annotations/Contract.html).  It won't check anything to do with the fields, which is why one would annotate the fields differently (with `@Nullable`, `@NonNull`, `@MagicConstant`, etc.).

Comment: But since I explicitely check for non-nullness in another method, can't I use the `@Contract` annotation to let IntelliJ know this? If I don't use the method but move the condition to the `if`-statement, IntelliJ *does* know things are OK.

Comment: `@Contract` only applies to the arguments you're passing in, not the state or behavior of any fields that the method may be using.  For that, you would use other annotations, including (but not limited to) `@Nullable`.  Further, static code analysis isn't going to be smart enough to pick up whether or not a field is non-null in one state and null in another; that's why the annotations are there to help guide it along.  I maintain with `@Nullable` that you're stating that you expect `mString` to be null at some point.

Comment: Although, now, I see where you're going with it.  It may be a limitation of how static analysis works.

Comment: Hmm, ok. There are verification tools which can do this. I was hoping this tool would be smart enough as well. See the updated question.

Comment: Give me a moment.  Let me see if I can dig around a bit to find something.  It'd kind of make sense that this would exist.

Comment: It would indeed :) I couldn't find much documentation on it besides the [page I linked to](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/-contract-annotations.html) unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry to say, but it may be a limitation after all.  The closest thing that may help is `@Flow`, but you would likely have to be modifying state in that method.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `@Contract` annotation for this, but you might have to change your isNull method to this:

```
@Contract("null -> true; !null -> false")
private boolean isNull(String value) {
  return value == null;
}
```

You should then be able to use your other method as this:

```
  public boolean contains(@NotNull final String text) {
    if(!isNull(text)) {
      return mString.contains(text);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

However, I am not sure how that would be preferable to this:

```
  public boolean contains(@NotNull final String text) {
    if(text != null) {
      return mString.contains(text);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Peter, I might have over simplified my problem a bit. I added an additional statement to the `isNullOrEmpty` method. Ofcourse, in this case the latter method is preferable, but I'm using the additional method in cases where the boolean expression becomes too complex.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this annotation? Are you merely trying to stop this warning in your code, or are you trying to expose this sort of functionality to your client code? If it is the warning you are concerned about, then you could overcome this by putting in an assert mString != null statement before the mString.contains call.

Comment: It is indeed the warning I am 'concerned' about. I know there are other ways to solve this, for example by using the assert statement, or passing in the parameter as others have mentioned. However, since Jetbrains introduced the `@Contract` annotation, I am trying to find out it's capabilities and limits.